# Limit FTP access only to the /var/www with vsftpd

Tags: ftp, chroot, vsftpd, account-restrictions

I am running vsftpd as ftp server on my linux (rasbian), I log in to the machine as a root user.

I would like to be still locked to using only /var/www, how can I configure vsftpd conf to accomplish it?

Comment: Check the `chroot `options in `vsftpd.conf` and create a separate user for it whose homedir is set to `/var/www`.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

### Method 1: Changing the user's home directory

Make sure the following line exists

```
chroot_local_user=YES
```

Set user HOME Directory to `/var/www/` , if you want to change for existing user then you can use:

```
usermod --home /var/www/ username
```

then set required permission on `/var/www/`

### Method 2: Use `user_sub_token`

If you don't want to change user's Home directory then you can use:

```
chroot_local_user=YES
local_root=/ftphome/$USER
user_sub_token=$USER
```

#### About `user_sub_token`:

> Automatically generate a home directory for each virtual user, based on a template.
>   For example, if the home directory of the real user specified via guest_username is
>   /ftphome/$USER, and user_sub_token is set to $USER, then when virtual user test 
>   logs in, he will end up (usually chroot()'ed) in the directory /ftphome/test.
>   This option also takes affect if local_root contains user_sub_token.

Create directory and set up permissions:

```
mkdir -p /ftphome/{test,user1,user2}
chmod 770 -R /ftphome
chown -R ftp. /ftphome
usermod -G ftp test
```

Once restart `vsftpd` and test your setup.

Sample success output:

```
[root@mail tmp]# ftp localhost
Connected to mail.linuxian.local.
220 (vsFTPd 2.0.5)
530 Please login with USER and PASS.
530 Please login with USER and PASS.
KERBEROS_V4 rejected as an authentication type
Name (localhost:root): test
331 Please specify the password.
Password:
230 Login successful.
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
ftp> mput vhosts
mput vhosts? 
227 Entering Passive Mode (127,0,0,1,146,41)
150 Ok to send data.
226 File receive OK.
24 bytes sent in 3.3e-05 seconds (7.1e+02 Kbytes/s)
ftp> ls -rlt
227 Entering Passive Mode (127,0,0,1,97,90)
150 Here comes the directory listing.
-rw-r--r--    1 787      787            24 Oct 11 19:57 vhosts
226 Directory send OK.
ftp> 221 Goodbye.
```

Comment: Note that you can have a suffix after `$USER` for `local_root`, such as `/home/$USER/ftp` (which will chroot users to the `ftp` subdirectory of their home dir).

Comment: Note remarks in vsftp FAQ regarding chrooting to folder writable by user logging in. This is highly probable in case of putting `local_root` into actual home directory of user.

Comment: Where to confirm that "chroot_local_user=YES" exist?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this:

```
usermod --home /var/www/ username
```

Comment: One to two line answers are often considered low quality. Please consider expanding your post with some explanation of what your recommendation does along with links or documentation that suggest your recommendation's ability to actually solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I used Rahul Patil's suggestion above:

```
chroot_local_user=YES
local_root=/home/$USER/www-data
user_sub_token=$USER
```

But I couldn't understand why I was only able to log in with one user. Then I found that we couldn't chroot to a root directory (for this case, `/home/$USER/www-data`) that have a write access. So I remove the write access with:

```
# chmod a-w /home/$USER/www-data
```

**NOTE:** change `$USER` with your user.

Answer (score 1):

Check the `chroot`options in `vsftpd.conf` and create a separate user for it whose homedir is set to `/var/www`.

Comment: I am well aware of that, I will create a separate user. I should maybe redesign my question then how can I limit a *user* to separate path *only*

Comment: Use sftp from OpenSSH. See man sshd_config for internal-sftp, then 'ForceCommand' and see 'ChrootDirectory'. Newer OpenSSH also added option for sftp-server to switch to a specific path, so in combination with ChrootDirectory you can do: chroot -> /path -> destination -> 'onlyhere' = /chroot/onlyhere