# Allow user access to their own dir, /var/www/html, nothing else

Tags: ssh, permissions

My company has a web designer that's going to upload files to /var/www/html and edit them. I created an account and will give them ssh access.

I added them to the apache group, but they can't access /var/www/html. Currently this is the set up of /var/www/html:

```
drwxr--r--  5 apache    apache 4096 11月  4 17:56 html
```

What would give them access to this directory but keep Apache limited? I can change it with `chmod 664 apache:apache -R` but what other suggestions do you have?

Comment: `/var/www/html` is a directory so needs to be both read (`r`) and executable (`x`) by anyone who needs access to it.  so 775 or 770 would be the right perms to allow owner and group `rwx`.

Comment: sorry my ignorance @cas : ) why a directory must be executable in order to be allowed to be accessed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual way of addressing this is to put the ftp/sftp users in a `chroot`, so that they can see only the directory tree which included.  The feature is described in several places.

To start:

- [Limit FTP access only to the /var/www with vsftpd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94603/limit-ftp-access-only-to-the-var-www-with-vsftpd)
- [chrooted sftp user with write permissions to /var/www](https://superuser.com/questions/669690/chrooted-sftp-user-with-write-permissions-to-var-www)
- [How to Setup Chroot SFTP in Linux (Allow Only SFTP, not SSH)](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/03/chroot-sftp-setup/)
- [How to jail / chroot users in FTP / SFTP](http://www.ochounos.com/blog/12)

Comment: Cool, thanks. That's just what I was looking for.

Comment: Okay, I've created a chroot for them. But I can't get them to access the /var/www/html folder. I did `mount --bind /var/tmp/chroot/var/www/html /var/www/html` but now /var/www/html appears as empty.