# Prevent FTP users from being able to navigate to directories above their home

Tags: ftp, home, webmin

I created a user on Centos 7 via webmin and pointed `/var/www/html/` page as their home directory so when they log in they start from there.

However, I logged in myself and realized that they can navigate from there to the upper directories which I don't want. How can I prevent this from happening?

Thank you.

Comment: You want to chroot the users.  To do this you'll need to modify the FTP server config.  IIRC webmin uses proftpd  - look at the DefaultRoot directive - http://www.proftpd.org/docs/directives/linked/config_ref_DefaultRoot.html

Answer (score 2):

You will need to find a feature specific to the ftp server you are using that could create a [chroot-like](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot) environment. Some examples are:

- **proftpd**: [DefaultRoot](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/directives/linked/config_ref_DefaultRoot.html). This option will have to point what is the chroot dir of a server.
- **pureftpd**: [`-A` option](https://download.pureftpd.org/pub/pure-ftpd/doc/FAQ). Quoting the documentation

> This feature is called "chroot". You can enable this by running
>   pure-ftpd with the "-A" switch to do this with ALL your users (but
>   root) .

- **vsftpd**: `chroot_local_user=YES` will chroot to default user home. There is already a [good answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/94673/34720).

Comment: its weird but I didnt install any ftp server so I dont even know how come I am able to FTP access.

Comment: As pointed out by @ivanivan, the default ftp server on webmin should be `proftpd`. It is just a matter of finding the configuration file and put a line like `DefaultRoot=/var/www/html/` on it :)

Comment: But that one is stopped right now and Im still able to access. Is that normal?

Comment: `netstat -tapn | grep 21`, and see what is the process that is `LISTENING` on this port(21/tcp - ftp)

Comment: I see nothing on port 21, the user is on port 22.

Comment: 22 is `ssh` so, `sftp` or `scp` are the protocols used to exchange files. Are you sure that is really an ftp server, and there is no custom port configured?

Comment: I dont know because I didnt install any FTP server myself. I only installed webmin and proftpd was already there but its stopped right now and Im still able to FTP access by using filezilla and setting it to sftp.

Comment: SFTP is and extension of FTP throuhg SSH. That's why you can access, because it is not related do proftpd. If you have a `ssh` daemon running on your server, you will mostly be able to use sftp... "chrooting" sftp is a hell of a quest, and should not be as trivial as it is with a ftp server...

Comment: So I need to enable chroot in SSH instead?

Comment: Yup. If you are using SFTP you started asking the wrong question, since they use totally different servers... and it is not a trivial question(you should follow a how-to) - https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SFTP_chroot

Comment: Thank you for your help. Although it was actually easier than that.