# vsftpd access to /srv/www/domain.com/somedir

Tags: ubuntu, vsftpd, user-mode-linux

On Ubuntu 16 I am trying to give FTP access to a particular server directory which has files owned by `web:www-data` to an FTP user.

I have [changed the users home directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/94673/68860):

```
usermod --home /srv/www/example.com/current/ username
```

Confirmed:

```
grep username /etc/passwd
```

username:x:1002:1001:User Company,,,:/srv/www/example.com/current/:/bin/bash

When I switch users the home directory seems to be the same as the admin directory:

```
sudo -su username
echo $HOME
/home/admin
```

And when I connect via FTP

```
ftp -p xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Name: username
Password: password
```

It takes me to `/home/username/ftp`

Answer (score 0):

Whoops. Looked in `/etc/vsftpd.conf` and lo and behold:

```
local_root=/home/$USER/ftp
```

Remove that line, restart (`sudo systemctl restart vsftpd`) and land in the desired directory.

Not sure how permissions will work out. I have added `username` to the `www-data` group. New to command-line FTP and still unable to connect via GUI FTP (FileZilla, Fetch).