# How can I lock an FTP user to their home directory?

Tags: centos, ftp, chroot, vsftp

I have found some [help](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94603/limit-ftp-access-only-to-the-var-www-with-vsftpd) regarding locking an FTP user to their home directory, but after following steps, I find I'm still able to run `cd ..` and exit that directory and browse the file system. I'm using CentOS 7. Here are my steps:

`yum install vsftpd ftp -y`

`systemctl enable vsftp && suystemctl start vsftpd`

I modify `/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf` and set `chroot_local_user=YES`.

`useradd lockeduser`

`passwd lockeduser`

Following prompts, I set the password.

`usermod --home /mnt/library/locked-folder lockeduser`

Once that has been configured, I `ftp` in and `open` a connection to the local IP.

I now land in the `locked-folder` directory, however I can navigate anywhere I want from there.

I feel I am missing something obvious.

Comment: Probably the `useradd` command - see [this](https://serverfault.com/a/479822).